# Antlr4 how to start

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I am developing a SQL-like language parser for my own language (let's call it MySQL. It contains SQL structures but adds some extra stuff.

My tool gets a MySQL query, parses it, changes stuff and generates a normal SQL query. Like Hibernate does.

I created the grammar file and it looks fine but I don't know what to do next.

For example: lets take this line:
 `SELECT a AS aa, b FROM tbl1`

and change it to

`SELECT string1, integer2 FROM server1[tbl1]`.

I have a map that converts tbl1.a -> string1, tbl1.b -> integer2.

How do I do this?

I created listeners but how can I connect a result column to its alias (for example)?

My grammar has these rules:

```
select_statement :  
    SELECT  result_column (AS? alias )? ( ',' result_column (AS? alias )? )* 
    FROM    from_cluase  ( ',' from_cluase (AS? alias )? )*
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extra parser rule for a `result` which includes the optional `alias`:

```
select_statement 
 : SELECT  result ( ',' result )* 
   FROM    from_cluase  ( ',' from_cluase (AS? alias )? )*
 ;

result
 : result_column (AS? alias )?
 ;
```

The `enterSelect_statement` method inside your listener will now give you access to a `List<ResultContext>` through its *context*. These `ResultContext`s can then be inspected for their `result_column` and optional `alias`.